# Python Multiple `self` Reference

Tags: python

I could be out of my mind thinking this way, but was wondering if the below is feasible or what's a better way of doing the following.

Let's say I have a class:

```py
class Alpha:

    def __getattr__(self, label):
        # Set the name / label
        self.label = label

        # Return the self instance
        return self

    def a_function(self):
        print(f'Label: {self.label}')
```

I can call class `Alpha` with something like:

```py
a = Alpha()

# Prints `Label: foo`
a.foo.a_function()
```

Now let's say I want to create a wrapper class:

```py
class Beta:

    def __getattr__(self, label):
        # Set the name / label
        self.label = label

        # Return the self instance
        return self

    def b_function(self):
        a = Alpha()

        # Does not work
        # But want to make a call like this
        a.self.label.a_function()
```

`Beta` is kind of a wrapper class, and I will call `Beta`, which in turn calls `Alpha` with the same `label` if you will:

```py
b = Beta()

# Want to call `a_function` from a `b` object with `__getattr__`
# Expect to print `Label: bar`
b.bar.b_function()
```

Comment: You should take a look at the definition of [inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance). You don't need to go over all this complicated code to do something so simple.

Comment: Why would it print `bar`? That's the label of `b`, but `a_function()` prints the label of `a`.

Comment: @Barmar I think that when he's attempting to call `a.self.label.a_function()` he thinks `self.label` is going to be printed... And in that case, `bar` is equal to `self.label`?

Comment: I find it hard to understand what you're trying to do. First of all you have a `__getattr__` that _sets_ the label? And then returns self... so you can call `a.foo.print_label()` and it prints "foo"? That makes little sense to me.

Comment: Second, what is b_function() supposed to do in class Beta? Is it not just another `print_label`?
I think what would help you is trying to come up with a more meaningful example, e.g. with concrete method names instead of generic "a" and "b" functions.

Comment: @Ricardo, yes, i am basically trying to pass a `__getattr__` value through 2 classes

Comment: @MarcelloRomani, basically when you call `a.foo.a_function()`, the `foo` value is passed into the class using dot (.) notation, similar to passing a parameter, so i can pass different value such as `a.value1.a_function()` or a.value2.a_function()`

Comment: @MarcelloRomani, the `b_function()` body is just an example filler code, pretend `Beta` class itself is a wrapper for `Alpha` class. So say you are working with an API call `Alpha` you can't change and you are writing a `Beta` wrapper around it, but you want to call the `Beta` wrapper the same way you call `Alpha`. Again, this might not be the best way to do it, but I want to see if is feasible

Answer (score -1):

Using [inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance), you can have a child class `Beta()` accessing (or calling) a function `a_function()` defined on the parent class `Alpha()`

```
class Alpha():
  def __getattr__(self, label):
    # Set the name / label
    self.label = label

    # Return the self instance
    return self

  def a_function(self):
    print(f'Label: {self.label}')


class Beta(Alpha):
  pass
```

Then:

```
a = Alpha()
a.bar.a_function()
# prints 'Label: bar'
b = Beta()
b.foo.a_function()
# prints 'Label: foo'
```

Comment: the problem with inheritance is what if I have `Alpha1` and `Alpha2` with the same `__getattr__` method and same `a_function()`? Such as `class B(Alpha1, Alpha2)`, if I call `b.foo.a_function()`, it doesn't know which class it goes to?

Comment: That is multiple inheritance. Different class of problems. If you keep changing requirements you won't get anywhere :-)

Comment: That's fair, I guess I am just trying to understand it from a personal perspective. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @YTKme I believe that if you have `Alpha1` and `Alpha2` with the same `__getattr__` and same `a_function()`, you don't actually need both of them, as they're exactly the same class... Am I right?

Comment: @Ricardo, yes and no, `a_function()` just an example, but `a_function()` can be two different method within `Alpha1` and `Alpha2` that is named the same